# Firebug throwing excessive script errors during normal browsing

Tags: javascript, firebug

I expect this might get some downvotes / closevotes but I'm going to ask anyway as I can't find an answer to this anywhere else, and I know that others who use Firebug on a daily basis must have noticed this too.

When I hit many "big" sites, such as Google, Paypal, Wordpress sites (especially the admin interface after a couple of plugins are active) and others with Firebug active, it can break on atleast 2-3 errors per page request. Normally it's undefined variables or something along those lines, quite often in jQuery (although what caused that error isn't).

This is very annoying >:( and much more frequent than I remember even a year ago. It happens alot on websites that you would expect to be well checked for script errors which is what I find to be the most puzzling - whenever Firebug reports an error on one of my sites, I fix it until none show up, ever. What's the difference here?

What I want to know is this: has firebug's error detection gotten alot stricter recently or have the general standards of script coding gotten worse - or a mix of both?

Or am I just being an idiot and have switched on super-uber-mega-strict error checking somehow?

Using Firebug 1.9.1 with Firefox 11.0 on Max OSX Lion.

the kind of thing I see more times a day than I should in a month:

[image]

p.s error is `a is null`, somewhere in the jQuery source.

Comment: That image is not at all readable.

Comment: @Pointy I know, it's more for context. Not interested in the specific errors thrown on specific pages or sites, just that there are so many on sites built by companies that can afford to fix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've stumbled on the fact that many big websites are badly coded.